# Event only activate when clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to hide/show a side-bar on my HTML page. The `.toggle("slide")` event will activate when an `<li>` element is pressed.

```
<div class="sidebar" id="SideBar"></div>

<!-- elsewhere in code... -->
<li style="//Styling li Button." id="toggle-bar" onclick="toggleEvent();">toggle bar</li>
```

```js
{
    $("#toggle-bar").click(function(){
        $("#SideBar").stop().toggle("slide"); // for left to right slide.
    });
}
```

I used `.stop()` to stop animation after one slide effect but the animation only takes place when user first focuses on the `<li>` element (by clicking on it).then clicking again to trigger animation (I'm assuming)

So, please tell me how to trigger animation only in one click

Comment: Have you missed the `function toggleEvent()` from your JS code, or have you really placed it in an anonymous object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused why you're using the html `onclick` and jquery's `.click()` together on the same element.

I would suggest removing the `onclick` from the html and remove the `.stop()` call, so then your animation is called once, instead of twice.
As mentioned by other comments, it would be good to know what `function toggleEvent()` is so we can provide a more accurate answer.

your html:

```
<div class="sidebar" id="SideBar"></div>

<!-- elsewhere in code... -->
<li style="//Styling li Button." id="toggle-bar">toggle bar</li>
```

your javascript:

```
$("#toggle-bar").click(function(){
    $("#SideBar").toggle("slide"); // for left to right slide.
});
```

or if you need `function toggleEvent()` to run instead, your javascript can look like:

```
$("#toggle-bar").click(toggleEvent);
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. After few Minutes I post This. I realized why i used "onclick" two times.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the JS code you've shown is the code block of the `toggleEvent()` function, like the below:

```
function toggleEvent() {
    $("#toggle-bar").click(function(){
        $("#SideBar").stop().toggle("slide"); // for left to right slide.
    });
}
```

The issue is that on the first click of the element you attach the event handler. Then on subsequent clicks you attach another event handler, and run any previous ones. This is why it only works after the first click.

To achieve what you require you can remove the `onclick` attribute completely and attach your event handler directly via JS. Try this:

```
<li style="" id="toggle-bar">toggle bar</li>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $("#toggle-bar").click(function(){
        $("#SideBar").stop().toggle("slide"); // for left to right slide.
    });
});
```